# ScrollPane jumps to top when deleting nodes

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, javafx-8

I have an `ScrollPane` containing a `TilePane` which shows images. Whenever I delete one of those images the `ScrollPane` jumps back to the top which is quite annoying when trying to remove multiple images. Is there a way to control the scrolling behaviour?

I'm running this code on Windows 7:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollbarProblem extends Application{
    private TilePane imagePane;
    private ScrollPane scroller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        imagePane = new TilePane();
        scroller = new ScrollPane();
        scroller.setContent(imagePane);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, null, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            Image img = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-220px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg");
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);

            final Button button = new Button("Delete");
            final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    imagePane.getChildren().remove(stackPane);
                }
            });

            stackPane.getChildren().addAll(imageView, button);
            imagePane.getChildren().add(stackPane);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds weird... can you [edit] your question to include a [MCVE] that shows the problem?

Comment: I edited a small example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScrollPane` makes sure the focused `Node` is shown inside the viewport. A `Button` that is clicked has the focus. This means the focused node is removed and JavaFX tries to move the focus to another node in the `ScrollPane` content, which in this case is the first `Button`. `ScrollPane` scrolls this node into view, which explains the observed behavior.

A solution would be setting the `focusTraversable` property of every `Button` to `false`.

Another option which would still allow you to change the focus via <kbd>Tab</kbd> would be overriding the `onTraverse` method of the `ScrollPaneSkin`, since this is the method responsible for this behavior:

```
scroller.setSkin(new ScrollPaneSkin(scroller) {

    @Override
    public void onTraverse(Node n, Bounds b) {
    }

});
```

Comment: Since tabbing through the buttons is not intended your solution is even easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be caused by the focus reverting to the button in the first element of the tile pane. One workaround is:

```
Image img = new Image(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-220px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg");

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);

    final Button button = new Button("Delete");
    final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();


    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            int index = imagePane.getChildren().indexOf(stackPane);

            imagePane.getChildren().remove(index);
            int numPanes = imagePane.getChildren().size();
            if (numPanes > 0) {
                imagePane.getChildren().get(Math.min(index, numPanes-1)).requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    stackPane.getChildren().addAll(imageView, button);
    imagePane.getChildren().add(stackPane);
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this answer is base on Fabian answer. in some JavaFx imp there is no `onTraverse` method on `ScrollPaneSkin`(see [javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/ScrollPaneSkin.html) vs [javafx.scene.control.skin.ScrollPaneSkin](https://jonathangiles.net/javafx/jdk9/jep253/1/javafx/scene/control/skin/ScrollPaneSkin.html)) so it can't be `@Override`, so I work for a general solution that will not include the need for every button change by the programmer, but it can get the root and set the `FocusTravers`= `false` whatever `Node`(`Button` in this imp) is added to the view tree.

This helper class:

```
public class FocusTraversHelper {

    static private ListChangeListener listChangeListener;
    static {
        listChangeListener=new ListChangeListener<Node>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Node> c) {
                if(c.next()&&c.wasAdded()){
                    Node b =c.getAddedSubList().get(0);
                    if(b!=null&&(b instanceof Parent || b instanceof Button) ){
                        cancelFocusTravers(b);
                    }
                }

            }};
    }
    static private void registerAddEvent(Parent parent){
        parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().removeListener(listChangeListener);
        parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener(listChangeListener);
    }
    static public void cancelFocusTravers(Node node){
        if(node instanceof Parent){
            registerAddEvent((Parent)node);
            for (Node n: ((Parent) node).getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
                cancelFocusTravers(n);
            }
        }
        if(node instanceof Button){
            node.setFocusTraversable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and the use is like:

```
  FocusTraversHelper.cancelFocusTravers(root);
```

Hope it will help someone

Note: if there is another control like `TextField` it should be modified in order to work(maybe use `Node` instead of `Button`).

Note: the remove->add needed in case of remove and add the same node multiple times, so there will be only one listener